# When did "brilliant" become a general term of approval in England?

Tags: etymology, slang

When did "brilliant" become a general term of approval unrelated to radiance or cleverness, e.g., as applied to a rural scene, a dish, or a sunset?

Comment: Probably ever since they became impervious to the "awesome" of Valley-Girl Speak. :) More seriously, it's a good question, and one whose answer isn't easy to pull out with a simple ngram.

Comment: The answer depends on the nuance you mean (but don't specify). *OED* attests figurative use more-or-less divorced from the senses 'radiant' and 'clever' going back to 1739. *OED* also attests a much more recent "weakened" colloquial sense, from 1971, more or less synonymous with "amazing, 'fantastic'". Do you want to split the *OED* hairs?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Etymonline the figurative usage is from the  mid-19th  century:

[Brilliant](https://www.etymonline.com/word/brilliant)

> Figurative sense of "distinguished by admirable qualities" is from 1848.